# Conditional jQuery Selector based on attributes using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I select a DOM element that has two data- attributes matching my values using jQuery?
My element is

```
<a data-published="true" data-i ="3"></a>
```

I need to select this element.

Comment: So, whats the issue and conditional?

Comment: `$('a[data-published=true][data-i=3]')` u can use it like this

Answer (score 2):

It will be `a[data-published="true"][data-i ="3"]`

```js
var $el = $('a[data-published="true"][data-i ="3"]');
console.log($el.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-published="true" data-i ="3"></a>
```

Comment: You may help the community more by flagging the dup question instead of answering them...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[data-published="true"]').val
```

so on your code..
if you want to match both then

```
$('a[data-published="true"][data-i="3"]').val
```